# Length do jQuery não atualiza com o append, como resolver?

Tags: jquery, ajax, front-end, append

Estou trabalhando num script que faz com que carregue mais registros do banco de dados quando o usuário chega ao final da rolagem da página.

O PHP/SQL está certinho, o problema é que o jQuery não informa corretamente o número de ocorrências de terminada `class` na tela.

Imagino que a solução seja implementar o `.on` de alguma maneira, mas não manjo muito de jQuery e estou me batendo com isso.

Explico meu código abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var posicaoAtual = $(window).scrollTop();
  var documentSize = $(document).height();
  var sizeWindow = $(window).height();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    posicaoAtual = $(window).scrollTop();
    //Até aqui, apenas verifico se o usuário chegou ao final da página. 

    if (posicaoAtual >= (documentSize - sizeWindow)) {
      //Agora que começa o sofrimento

      // Conta a quantidade de vezes que a section.empresa aparece na tela
      var qtdRegistros = $("#empresas section.empresa").length;

      //Variável que utilizo no meu PHP
      var idClientes = $("#idClientes").val();

      // Faz requisição ajax
      $.post("carrega-registros.php", {
        qtdRegistros: qtdRegistros,
        idClientes: idClientes
      }, function(resposta) {
        // Coloca o conteudo na DIV
        $("#empresas").append(resposta);
      });
    }
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    posicaoAtual = $(window).scrollTop();
    documentSize = $(document).height();
    sizeWindow = $(window).height();
  });
});
```

[EDIT 1]

O código todo funciona certinho. Meu retorno são novas `section class='empresa'` dentro da `div id="empresas"`.

PORÉM pela `var qtdRegistros = $("#empresas section.empresa").length;`, a variável `qtdRegistros` só identifica o número de vezes que aparece a `class` `empresa` no HTML original. Desconsiderando o que vem do `append`. Isso faz com que meu PHP traga resultados duplicados, já que a `qtdRegistros` é sempre a mesma.

Preciso atualizar o `length` de acordo com as novas `class` que vem no `append`. Mas isso não acontece.

Pesquisando muito achei algo semelhante implementando o `on`, mas simplesmente não consegui utilizar. Alguém consegue me indicar um caminho?

Comment: Podes colocar na pergunta o conteúdo de `resposta`?

Comment: Oi Sérgio! O script não apresenta erros. O que acontece é que sempre vai o mesmo valor pro PHP da variável qtdRegistros. Assim, ao invés de eu trazer novos registros no append, voltam sempre os mesmos.

Comment: @AryanaValcanaia o retorno do `post` é um `html`?

Comment: Isso mesmo :) 

O retorno é um append de um trecho como esse "<section class="empresa" id="11216"> (...) </section>" na div #empresas.

Comment: O que parece que acontece é que você tá pegando o elemento mesmo e o `append` não atualiza o conjunto de elementos dentro dele, mas o **conjunto** de filhos dele. Tenta `$("#empresas").children().length` e vê se resolve seu problema...

Comment: encontrei uma solução porem para a versão `1.10` do jquery, qual a versão voce usa?

Comment: @RafaelAcioly v2.1.1. Mas acredito que tenha resolvido com a solução do Felipe :) logo retorno aqui. Muito obrigada!

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Acredito que funcionoooou! Parece que minha função pra verificar se o usuário chegou ao final da página é que tá meio bugada agora :( vou fazer alguns testes e confirmo se é a solução mesmo! Obrigada.

Comment: Oi Aryana. Pelo que entendi você quer a quantidade exata de elementos antes de fazer o Ajax, é isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é que o `append` não atualiza a quantidade de elementos dentro do conjunto do elemento que você está acessando, mas sim a quantidade de filhos desse elemento.

Para resolver esse problema, altere a linha:

```
var qtdRegistros = $("#empresas section.empresa").length;
```

Para o seguinte:

```
var qtdRegistros = $("#empresas").children().length;
```

Comment: Meu código compila "certinho". Acredito que exista outro problema nele (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257693/voltar-a-executar-o-jquery-apenas-depois-de-um-tempo) :/ mas você ajudou bastante, obrigada!

Comment: Vou justificar meu downvote: essa sua sugestão não altera nada o código, só troca 6 por meia-dúzia.

Answer (score 1):

Quando inserir um novo `elemento HTML` com o `append` insira passando ele como um objeto `jquery`, veja:

```js
$( document.body )
  .click(function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<div class='mydiv'>" ) );
    var n = $( "div.mydiv" ).length;
    $( "span" ).text( "There are " + n + " divs. Click to add more." );
  })
 
  // Trigger the click to start
  .click();
```

```css
  body {
    cursor: pointer;
    min-height: 100px;
  }
  div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
  }
  span {
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
<div class="mydiv"></div>
```

Este exemplo foi encontrado na [documentação **depreciada da função `size()`**](https://api.jquery.com/size/)

No seu caso seria algo do tipo:

```
...
var qtdRegistros = $("#empresas section.empresa").length;
...
$("#empresas").append($('resposta'));
```

Tente alterar também a ordem das linhas, primeiro faça a inserção com `append` e depois a contagem.